# Is it possible to get mail in emacs from some sort of file dump or similar?

Tags: emacs, ssh, outlook

This may be highly nontrivial to do but I was wondering the other day if it would be possible to have a windows application like outlook trigger putty upon receipt of an email message so it can `scp` the message over to a linux host in which existing emacs instances would be able to detect and "receive" the email.

Comment: Why did you not simply use IMap with two differents mailer? Emacs is a mail client too, able to connect to imap servers!

Comment: You could even does the job in the other way: Fetch your mails into your Linux before, than share them with a little imap server...